# Superimpose OTB application via Sextante cannot load parameter

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, sextante, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to perform a pansharpening using OTB via sextante. According to the cookbook I first need to superimpose the Pan and XPS images:

http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu36.html

However I get the following error in my log:

ERROR: Troubles loading parameter, please check your line argument...
This is the Superimpose application, version 4.2.1
Using available image metadata, project one image onto another one

I am using Qgis 2.4.0 and OTB both installed via Osgeo4W 32 bit installer.
My images are WorldView2.

Does anyone know what is causing this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there must be something wrong in the parsing in the processing module. Please submit a bug in this case to qgis team.

An other test that could be made on your side and could help to find out the problem could be to test with the Monteverdi2 application (OTB GUI):

http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/monteverdi.html

With Monteverdi2 there is the same Superimpose GUI, if your able to reproduce the issue in Monteverdi2 it could be a problem on the OTB side.

Please let us know.

Manuel

Comment: I downloaded Monteverdi2 and imported the images. However the program kept "not responding" so I could not properly test. I did recreate the error once more via Sextante. What is the procedure to submit a bug?

Comment: For qgis - http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues